# simple color assignment not working in XTK with GWT (mesh.color = [0.7,0,0])

Tags: xtk

@haehn Hi Haehn (XTK)

I'm using edge-XTK with GWT and trying to render a simple STL. However XTK code fails at the line where we assign color to the mesh.

```
mesh.color = [0.7,0,0] // this line fails
```

Error message emitted by XTK code: `"Invalid color"`

This behavior is observed only when using XTK with GWT.

The error seems to be coming from this XTK code snippet

```
X.displayable.prototype.__defineSetter__('color', function(color) {

  // we accept only numbers as arguments
  if (!goog.isDefAndNotNull(color) || !(color instanceof Array) ||
      (color.length != 3)) {

    throw new Error('Invalid color.');

  }
```

I'm guessing that the issue is with the way GWT builds page with iframes... because of which  the above if condition could be failing in GWT. I think if you replace the above check with following snippet (got idea from: [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=p7uyWPcVGZsC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=isDefAndNotNull&source=bl&ots=x75PQwN1sL&sig=rkHLnkuvvTWLT1fFWlqL1KJFnrI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nzveT867IYrK6gGYwLWhCw&sqi=2&ved=0CE4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=isDefAndNotNull&f=false)). 
It might fix the problem.

```
use goog.isArray(color) instead of (color instanceof Array)
```

Can you please investigate and comment?

### Edit:

Hi XTK

Here is the code snippet which shows how I'm using XTK with GWT.

```
public class TestGwtXtk implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {
    testXtk();
}

    // GWT JSNI method, which allows mixing Java and JS natively. 
    // it is akin using c++ or c libraries in java or android

private native void testXtk() /*-{
    var r = new $wnd.X.renderer3D();
    r.container = 'xtk_container'; // div ele
    r.config.PROGRESSBAR_ENABLED = false;
    r.init();

    cube = new $wnd.X.cube();
    cube.lengthX = cube.lengthY = cube.lengthZ = 20;
    cube.color = [ 1, 1, 1 ]; // fails here in XTK code
    cube.center = [ 0, 0, 0 ]; // fails here in XTK code
    r.add(cube);
    r.render();
}-*/;
```

}

As noted by the inline comments, use of javascript array fails. Failure is not because js array usage, such as [0,0,0] or new Array(0,0,0) is wrong. Failure is because the way XTK code checks for "instance of Array".

### Edit: 2

Dear XTK

I was able to checkout XTK code from git, make changes that I'm proposing, re-build XTK.js and finally test successfully that my fix solves the problem.

for example: in displayable.js I commented one line and added another line thus:

```
// if (!goog.isDefAndNotNull(color) || !(color instanceof Array) || (color.length != 3)) {

if (!goog.isDefAndNotNull(color) || !(goog.isArray(color)) || (color.length != 3)) {
```

I made similar changes in couple of other places in the xtk codebase to get my usecase going. Explanation of why this is the right solution is here: [Closure: The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=p7uyWPcVGZsC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=goog.isArray&source=bl&ots=x76MHrN7xR&sig=Bo2pAEmf3PrkTQN2HchpPQdqSPE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_446UMCeMe_ZigLWoIDwDA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=goog.isArray&f=false). Would you please consider making this fix in the codebase for release 8? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using XTK with GWT ? What do you mean ? Did you write your own wrappers to compile code with xtk calls from Java to JavaScript ? Or do you directly use xtk.js in the war file and write manualy some JavaScript using it ? Or do you only use GAE (Google App Engine), the Google environnement for web applications (the ones made with GWT, but also not compiled from Java ones). Could you be more accurate please ?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943805/javascript-instanceof-typeof-in-gwt-jsni) they deal with some issues with GWT and type test, did you try to create your array with the "new" operator ?

```
var mycolor = new Array(0.7,0,0);
mesh.color = mycolor;
```

Comment: 1 positive vote but not set as "solved", any news ? Was it the issue ? Or can you bring us more informations ?

Comment: Hello, sorry about the delay in response. I had to try everything on my end before replying. I'm using XTK as JSNI function inside GWT, where GWT allows mixing Javascript with Java. In my application, XTK code is purely in Javascript (wrapped as GWT JSNI). So there is no difference between my JSNI function and your simplest sample code . .. And yes using "new Array(0.7,0,0)" instead of "[0.7,0,0]" does not solve the problem. Per my research using "goog.isArray(color) instead of (color instanceof Array)" in the XTK codebase, will solve this problem. Thanks for any additional pointers.

Comment: can you open an issue on github? then we can fix it before the next release

Comment: dear xtk. i have edited my original question with a snippet of how i'm using xtk with gwt. this is in response to your request to describe my usage pattern. hopefully this snippet suffices. thank you.